# How to make two-way scrollable view in android?

Tags: android, excel

I need to show a big table with two-dimensions scroll, like Excel's sheet. It can be very big, up to 1000 rows (and ~10 columns).

So, all the solutions that I have found based on ListView-into-HorizontalScrollView idea. It is too slow to be usable.

I tried to use WebView, but it is even slower that scrollable-into-scrollable.

Maybe I can get a bitmap of my listLayout and put it into HorizontalScrollable on every update? Or use some other kind of magic magic? Or maybe I can use some lib?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea:

- ListView for rows
- Each row is a separate horizontal LinearLayout, each child view is a cell
- The LinearLayout is wrapped in a HorizontalScrollView, so each item in the ListView is a HorizontalScrollView.
- When scrolling horizontally, scroll all the HorizontalScrollViews at the same time so they all stay the vertically aligned with each other.

It doesn't seem like having all those HorizontalScrollViews would be efficient, but they can render a single row much faster than one HorizontalScrollView can render an embedded ListView.

Now, how to do the horizontal scroll?  You have two choices:

1. Propagate the swiping events on a single HorizontalScrollView to all the others.  Pro: easier to code.  Con: Because of thread delays, the swiped HSV  may not stay exactly in sync with the other HSVs.
2. Grab swipe events from a central place, like an override on the ListView, and propagate them to the HSVs.  Pro: cleaner display.  Con:  harder to code with all the onInterceptTouchEvent and onTouchEvent voodoo necessary to capture swipes.

Another drawback to this approach is that the views for the cells in the horizontal LinearLayout need to have explicit widths set, otherwise the columns won't line up.

I couldn't in good conscience recommend this unless I tried it, so I hacked together some code.  You can see it at [android-table-test project on Github](https://github.com/klarson2/android-table-test)

I have a data source with 18 columns and 36K rows and it seems to scroll nicely (both ways) on all my devices.

Comment: Not to speak of.  This is open source, man!  The code is the documentation.  :)  There is sample code in the GitHub project, plus people do ask questions here on SO.

I am going to play around with the Lollipop RecyclerView and see if I can get a grid that scrolls both ways.  If I get it to work, I'll update my answer.  I assume that if adding support lib v7 to your project would mean the difference between the grid working and not working, you could add it.

Comment: @sleeply4cat I updated my answer with another concept, you can have a look at my code and see what you think,

Comment: tnx, I'll test it in a few days.

Comment: eclipse? Why not Android Studio?)

Comment: Haven't made the jump yet.  I started an app for my company this past summer, once it goes out (in the next few weeks) I will transition to Studio.